# How to make dropdown link only visible to a certain group of users?

Tags: permissions, security, publishing-page, dropdown, top-link-bar

So we have a Management Meeting every two  weeks and inside there is confidential information. Basically we want to make it so that link for this site/page is not even visible except to users within a certain security group. Is this possible? Is there a simple solution to achieve this?

Thanks
Tudor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks! I actually just stopped inheriting permissions for the specific page and created a group containing just the users I want. Now If a user logs in and is not part of said group, he/she can't even see the link to the page. This is a good way of doing it right?

I did not try the SPSecurityTrimmed control yet but this seems to satisfy my needs. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can put the link inside SPSecurityTrimmedControl control like this
 
    <%--content %>

Following link shows the possible values for Permission String:
http://sympmarc.com/2008/12/31/spsecuritytrimmedcontrol-possible-values-for-permissionsstring/